# How to add an external package to my node ROS2

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 18.04 ros2 Dasing C++

Hi, I don't understand well where my CMakeLists get the packages, but it takes the ones installed when I installed ROS2 (std_msgs, sensor_msgs, rclcpp...), now I want to get a package from another directory, in this case I want to find armadillo.

I think this have to be easy, but I dont figure out how to do it.

When I try to look for armadillo with  `find_package(armadillo REQUIRED)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` an error jump to my terminal:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):   By
> not providing "Findarmadillo.cmake" in
> CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project   has
> asked CMake to find a package
> configuration file provided by
> "armadillo", but CMake did not find
> one.
>
> Could not find a package
> configuration file provided by
> "armadillo" with   any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> armadilloConfig.cmake
> armadillo-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "armadillo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
> set   "armadillo_DIR" to a directory
> containing one of the above files.  If
> "armadillo" provides a separate
> development package or SDK, be sure it
> has   been installed.

I tried several things in touching the CMakeLists.txt but no one works, I added this in the package.xml too:

```
  <build_depend>armadillo</build_depend>      
  <exec_depend>armadillo</exec_depend>
```

And this is what I have about armadillo in my CMakeLists.txt at the moment:

```
find_package(armadillo REQUIRED)

add_library(armadillo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(armadillo PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/user/armadillo/armadillo-9.850.1)
    
add_executable(editer src/imagediter.cpp )

ament_target_dependencies(editer
 "armadillo"
 "rclcpp" 
 "std_msgs" 
 "opencv2" 
 "sensor_msgs" 
 "cv_bridge" 
)
```

Maybe is not necessary, but I post it can be usefull

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344774/how-to-add-an-external-package-to-my-node-ros2/) by [Waboqueox](https://answers.ros.org/users/51660/waboqueox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, thanks to @marguedas, that realized about Armadillo is written with uppercase "A", and providing a link to armadillo CMake. Some friends noticed that armadillo needs:

```
target_link_libraries(editer ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
```

too, to works, so finally it works with:

```
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)

add_executable(editer src/imagediter.cpp )
target_link_libraries(editer ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
ament_target_dependencies(editer
 "Armadillo"
 "rclcpp" 
 "std_msgs" 
 "opencv2" 
 "sensor_msgs" 
 "cv_bridge" 
 )
```

Don't know if all packages works in the same way, so I let this for other people having the same problems, remember to check your package cmake here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/index.html

---

Originally posted by [Waboqueox](https://answers.ros.org/users/51660/waboqueox/) with karma: 11 on 2020-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waboqueox](https://answers.ros.org/users/51660/waboqueox/) on 2020-02-21**:
Don't know if this is relative to ROS2 or to CMake, is true that the problem and solution cames from CMake, but `colcon build` uses cmake and I found this problem using ROS2, so im confused about if post this things here or not, or where to ask then

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-21**:
that's fair enough it's not necessarily evident what is CMake related and what comes from ROS code :+1:

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a pure CMake question unrelated to ROS. I encourage you to search on other fora for this kind of non-ROS question in the future.

In this case the name of the library is `Armadillo` and CMake is case sensitive. to find it you need to:

```
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
```

Example on the official CMake documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindArmadillo.html

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waboqueox](https://answers.ros.org/users/51660/waboqueox/) on 2020-02-21**:
Ops, seems that was te reason, but I still have errors trying to compile my executable...  `reference to 'wrapper2_dgemv_ 'undefined` and one warning that I can not fix:

```
 `is deprecated: publishing an unique_ptr is prefered when using intra process communication. If using a shared_ptr, use publish(*msg). [-Wdeprecated-declarations`]
```

I'm new in this forum, isn't here where I can answer about my `colcon build` results? where I should ask then? thanks

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-21**:\

> I'm new in this forum, isn't here where I can answer about my colcon build results? where I should ask then?
> Yes this is the right venue for ROS questions. My remark was because your original question was about how to find a non-ROS library in CMake so it was not a "ROS question"

> but I still have errors trying to compile my executable...

This looks like a different question. Could you please open a new question with the full error messages? as well as information and code to provide enough context for people to help you find the issue.
You can see [this wiki page](https://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) for guidelines for asking questions.

> Ops, seems that was te reason

Please consider accepting the answer above (by clicking the checkmark on the left) if it solved your original question

**Comment by [Waboqueox](https://answers.ros.org/users/51660/waboqueox/) on 2020-02-21**:
mmm, I was considering it, but I'm not still sure if that fixed my problem, because in the theory the next error appears when it doesn't find the package... So I don't know if the package has been added correctly to my node.

Don't know if I should edit my question or open a new one. If I open a new one, and fix the problem then I can see if this works correctly, and then check as solution.

**Comment by [Waboqueox](https://answers.ros.org/users/51660/waboqueox/) on 2020-02-21**:
I can't mark my own answer as solution because I need a kind of points (this is not a game, just a forum to find solutions to a problem relative to ROS, I don't care about points), if you want, publish an answer or edit this one adding the

```
target_link_libraries(editer ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
```

And I chek as solution :D

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-21**:
I upvoted your answer, this should hopefully give you enough points to accept your answer